# Obtaining $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^n \cos{(n\theta)} = \frac{a \cos{\theta}-a^2}{1-2a\cos{\theta}+a^2}$

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series

This is a homework problem. From Fourier Series and Boundary Value problems, Brown/Churchill 8th ed.

I should begin with $2\cos{A}\cos{B}=\cos{(A+B)}+\cos{(A-B)}$, substitute with $A=n\theta$ and $B=\theta$, and sum from $n=1$ to $\infty$ both sides. So far I got here

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^n \cos{(n\theta)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n\cos{(n\theta+\theta)}+a^n\cos{(n\theta-\theta)}}{2\cos{\theta}}$

Hints on how to proceed from here?

Comment: Hint : $\cos n\theta$ is the real part of $e^{in\theta}$

Comment: Your approach will work, I suppose. $n\theta +\theta=(n+1)\theta$.

Comment: @Snowflake,   See Article$\#76$ of https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00hobs

Answer (score 1):

Consider that: $$\cos(n\theta)=\frac{\mathbb e^{n\theta i}+\mathbb e^{-n\theta i}}{2}$$ So: $$r^n\cos(n\theta)=\frac{r^n\mathbb e^{n\theta i}+r^n\mathbb e^{-n\theta i}}{2}$$ When: $|r|\lt1$, both of the following series are convergence:$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n\mathbb e^{n\theta i}\,\,\,,\,\,\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n\mathbb e^{-n\theta i}$$ Thus: 
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n\cos(n\theta)&=\frac12(\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n\mathbb e^{n\theta i}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n\mathbb e^{-n\theta i})\\
&=\frac12(\frac{r\mathbb e^{i\theta}}{1-r\mathbb e^{i\theta}})+\frac12(\frac{r\mathbb e^{-i\theta}}{1-r\mathbb e^{-i\theta}})
\end{align}
$$